# the square of integral vs. the integral of square of a nonnegative function

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

It is known that $\sum |x_i|^2\leq (\sum |x_i|)^2$ for finite sums. Do we have a similar inequality for integrals, namely $$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx\leq \left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx\right)^2?$$

Comment: It's not true. Have you tried $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Doesn't the opposite inequality hold? According to Cauchy-Schwartz

Comment: your inequality holds iff $|f|$ is a.e. constant

Comment: Oops! Stupid me. I think I should go to sleep. Thank you all.

Comment: Perhaps you can kindly delete this post? It's not going to be useful to any future readers unless you edit and make it into a different question.